# Blender Compositing not working

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

As stated in the title, my blender compositor is not working.

I have followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWcCkQ3943Y) but the compositor effects do not show up, even after rendering the image completely. What could I have missed?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Sorry typo, I meant not rather than now in the title question.

Comment: First thing to check : is the rendered view in render layer or composite layer ?

Comment: If you need to add additional information you can click the [edit] link below the question to edit it.

Comment: In the header of the node editor check that ["Use nodes"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/properties.html#header) is enabled.

Comment: I already have checked the use nodes button, it doesn't fix the problem. I have checked and it looks like i'm in render layer. Any way to change it and see if it does something?

Comment: Yes I did run the compositing again, I also checked that the post-processing compositor box was checked, it was.

Comment: Where are you previewing results of the compositing - in the Node Editor or UV/Image editor ? Are there Composite and Viewer nodes in the nodetree, both connected to the output of the tree ? Can you edit your question with a screenshot ? If they are present and connected and no result neither in Viewer nor in UV/Image edtior please [upload the blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Sorry, i'm a newbie to blender stack exchange. How can I upload a screenshot to blender?

Comment: The screenshot is what a immediately loaded up node editor blender section looks like. I already have set up use nodes and the other things as you can see.

Comment: Is the compositor box enabled in Scene>Post-processing? have you pressed f12 to render?

Comment: Yes, I have rendered it and enabled post-processing but still nothing.

Comment: UV/Image editor is not opened but Composite node will show results only there. Split the window, choose UV/Image editor from editor's list to open editor and try running compositing again. To preview compositing results in the Node Editor add Viewer node.

Comment: Looks like that fixed it. Haven't had any more problems after repeatedly trying different things. Thanks a bunch for all the help everyone, its solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that fixed it. Haven't had any more problems after repeatedly trying different things. Thanks a bunch for all the help everyone, its solved.

-Edit for those who are confused: The viewer node didn't fix it but [Mr Zak's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73365/blender-compositing-not-working/73389#comment128068_73365) did:

> UV/Image editor is not opened but Composite node will show results only there. Split the window, choose UV/Image editor from editor's list to open editor and try running compositing again. To preview compositing results in the Node Editor add Viewer node.

Comment: If you are going to write an answer at least explain what fixed your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to posting things in forums in general so I wasn't and still am not extremely confident in my ability to post questions and answers

Comment: No worries, stack exchange works a bit differently from a lot of forums. You might want to take a second to check out the [tour] if you haven't already.

Answer (score -1):

In the *Composite* tab on the upper left there's a check box that reads *Use nodes*. Check it and you will se the nodes